# Exit without saving from "nano -t"

Tags: nano

Usually I use `nano` editor but with `-t` parameter.
From `man nano`:

```
   -t (--tempfile)
          Always save changed buffer without prompting.  Same as Pico’s -t option.
```

It just doesn't ask me about saving yes/no and save to this file or another one.

So, it won't ask when I going to exit. But when this file is `readonly` I couldn't find a way to exit excepting save this file in different path.

Is there any way to exit without saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution for nano, but a workaround:

Use a shell function and test before opening, if the file is writable.

---

Open your `.bashrc`

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add the code below

```
mynano() {
    if [ -w "$1" ]; then
            nano -t "$1"
    else
            echo "$1 isn't writable"
    fi
}
```

save the file and reload the configuration.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

*Example*

```
$ ls -la foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4 Sep 12 14:01 foo

$ whoami
notroot

$ mynano foo
foo isn't writable
```